# VSCode Go To Definition does not Work on `import './index.css'`

Tags: visual-studio-code

From what I understand, [issue 29899 of vscode](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/29899#issue-239643470) solved this problem... except, for me it does not appear to be working.

I just want to be able to right click and click "Go to definition" and open a css file from an import statement, instead of having to dig through the folder tree to open it. But it doesn't work.

What do I need to do to get this working?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/67860667/836330 as of v1.57 this might be solved for you.

Answer (score -1):

This was working for me on VSCode but it wasn't working on VSCode Insiders.

Now after the latest release of [Insiders](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/) (1.53.0) it works as well there.

That makes me think that perhaps a fresh install will solve it for you, as that update did basically that.